# Como imprimir toda a string se o comprimento ultrapassar a página

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Eu tenho que imprimir uma *string* que pode variar de tamanho. O que preciso é que se esta *string* não couber na página o texto restante seja impresso em outra. Sei que para isso preciso fazer algo usando `e.HasMorePages` mas não sei como. Andei pesquisando mas não achei nada relevante. Deem uma olhada em parte do código que consta no evento `printPage`:

```
string textoFinal = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + cabInf + cab + sb.ToString() + soma + stringObs + final + final2;

StringFormat alinhar = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);

alinhar.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

e.Graphics.DrawString(textoFinal, Fonte, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, alinhar);

e.HasMorePages = false;
```

Se eu seto para `true` o `e.HasMorePages` ao imprimir recebo um loop de contagem de páginas. Preciso de algo que cheque se a string ultrapassou o limite da página e, se ultrapassou, o texto que não coube deve ser impresso em outra página.

**EDIT**
Tenho este código para imprimir:

```
string textoFinal;
string stringCopia;

internal void Imprimir()
{
    Cliente cliente = Clientes[listaClientes.SelectedIndex];

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var cli in cliente.Produtos)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("\n\n{0}.....................Valor: R${1} - Data: {2}", cli.NomeProduto, cli.ValorProduto, cli.DataCompra);
    }
    textoFinal = sb.ToString();
    stringCopia = textoFinal;
    printDocumento.PrintPage += printDocumento_PrintPage;
    Margins margem = new Margins(20, 20, 20, 20);
    printDocumento.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margem;
    printPrevisao.ShowDialog();
}
```

No evento `printPage` consta:

```
int caracteresNaPagina = 0;
int linhasPorPagina = 0;

var Fonte = new Font("Arial", 9);

e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.logoI, 20, 20);

StringFormat alinhar = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);

alinhar.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringCopia, Fonte, e.MarginBounds.Size, alinhar, out caracteresNaPagina, out linhasPorPagina);

e.Graphics.DrawString(stringCopia, Fonte, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, alinhar);

stringCopia = stringCopia.Substring(caracteresNaPagina);

e.HasMorePages = stringCopia.Length > 0;

if (!e.HasMorePages)
    stringCopia = textoFinal;
```

Desta maneira o restante do texto que não coube na página está sendo escrito no começo da mesma página, embaralhando os textos ao invés de passar para outra página.
**RESOLUÇÃO DO PROBLEMA**
Funcionou perfeitamente após a remoção da linha `printDocumento.PrintPage += printDocumento_PrintPage;`
Por quê? Porque eu estou desenvolvendo isso no winforms e já tinha este método apontando para o evento. Desta forma, o texto era escrito duas vezes no documento de impressão e se embaralhava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que precisa de fazer e medir o texto que vai imprimir:

```
int caracteresNaPagina = 0;
int linhasPorPagina = 0;

e.Graphics.MeasureString(textoFinal, font,
    e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
    out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);
```

De seguida imprime o texto e retira ao texto original os caracteres que já foram imprimidos. Se ainda houverem caracteres, coloca a propriedade `HasMorePages` a `true`.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(textoFinal, font, Brushes.Black,
    e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

textoFinal= textoFinal.Substring(caracteresNaPagina);

e.HasMorePages = (textoFinal.Length > 0);
```

Desta forma o evento continuará a ser chamado até deixaram de existir caracteres para imprimir, i.e, quando `HasMorePages` for colocado a falso.

Note que o texto a imprimir tem de ser criado previamente (fora do evento de impressão).

EDIT:

O controlo `PrintPreviewDialog` que esta a usar para fazer o *preview* do documento a imprimir chama por duas vezes o evento `PrintPage`. A primeira vez quando esta a criar o *preview* e a segunda vez se o botão de imprimir for carregado (e a impressao for efectivada).

Devido a isso e assumindo que o texto foi criado fora do evento `PrintPage`, devido a lógica para calcular as paginas extras, o texto vai sendo retirado ate nao sobrarem caracteres para imprimir.

```
textoFinal= textoFinal.Substring(caracteresNaPagina);

e.HasMorePages = (textoFinal.Length > 0);
```

O problema disto, e que a segunda vez que for imprimir, ao reutilizar `textoFinal`, ja nao existem caracteres a imprimir, dai a impressao efectiva aparecer a branco. A solução para isto será então.

- Criar o texto a imprimir
- Criar uma copia do texto a imprimir
- Usar a copia criada dentro do evento `PrintPage`

Ou seja:

```
string textoFinal = [crie aqui o seu texto];
string copiaTextoFinal = textoFinal; // Copia do texto. Vao ser removidos caracteres a medida que a impressao ocorre.
PrintPreviewDialog dialog = new PrintPreviewDialog
    {
        Document = new PrintDocument()
    };

dialog.Document.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        int charactersOnPage;
        int linesPerPage;

        var fonte = new Font("Arial", 18);

        e.Graphics.MeasureString(copiaTextoFinal, fonte,
                e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
                out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(copiaTextoFinal, fonte, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        copiaTextoFinal = copiaTextoFinal.Substring(charactersOnPage);

        // Verifica se ainda existem caracteres para imprimir. Se não, marca a 
        // propriedade como falsa.
        e.HasMorePages = copiaTextoFinal.Length > 0;

        // Se não houverem mais paginas a imprimir, volta a copiar o texto original
        // para a variável de copia. Assim, da próxima vez que o evento for chamado, 
        // tem o texto completo, pronto a imprimir.
        if (!e.HasMorePages)
            copiaTextoFinal = textoFinal;
    };

dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Este foi o primeiro método que usei, vi lá no MSDN. Estava tentando colocando o texto a ser impresso dentro do evento `printPage`. Tentei colocando o texto no código que chama o evento. O texto aparece pra mim no preview mas a folha sai em branco quando imprimo. No preview da impressão o texto que não cabe no final da folha está ficando embaralhado no início da folha.

Comment: Na minha função para imprimir consta `printDocumento.PrintPage += printDocumento_PrintPage;
Margins margem = new Margins(20, 20, 20, 20);
printDocumento.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margem;
printPrevisao.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Não tenho reputação alta o suficiente para usar o bate-papo.

Comment: O `printPrevisao.ShowDialog();` está dentro da função  `OnClick` de um botão.

Comment: Estou examinando e vendo como poderei implementar aqui!
O texto no caso não pode ser criado dentro do evento junto com a cópia?

Comment: Nao, caso contrario vai criar o texto de cada vez que o evento correr, dessa forma nao tem forma de saber que texto e que ja foi impresso.

Comment: O seu código funcionou em partes. Agora a folha é impressa mas o restante da string que não coube na página fica embaralhado no começo da folha ao invés de imprimir em outra folha.

Comment: Mesmo substituindo pelo meu `StringFormat alinhar` o texto continua embaraçado no começo da página. O que pode estar dando errado?

Comment: Estive a testar o seu codigo. O seu problema e o logo? Com o seu codigo, o logo fico em cima das primeiras linhas de impressao.

Comment: Eu uso `\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n` pra descer o texto na página. O problema no caso está sendo as páginas mesmo. Ao invés do texto restante passar para outra página, ele volta lá no começo e se mistura com a imagem e com o texto. Só tenho uma página no preview. Precisaria ter duas: uma com a imagem e com o texto e a outra com o texto que não coube.

Comment: Para comecar, devia resolver esse erro. O texto nao devia ser descido com `\n` mas sim ajustadando a forma como a imagem esta a ser desenhada na pagina (manipulando as coordenadas x e y)

Comment: Mesmo removendo a linha que desenha a imagem os textos continuam embaraçados lá no início. Acho que tem algo errado na contagem de páginas.

Comment: Omni, nos seus testes você obteve sucesso passando parte do texto que não coube para outra página sem o mesmo retornar para o começo e embaraçar?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente após a remoção da linha `printDocumento.PrintPage += printDocumento_PrintPage;`. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!